# HTML Header Alignment

Tags: html, css, menu, header

I am trying to create a header that contains an image along with links that will act as a nav menu for users to navigate.I want the layout to look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eqNH.png).

However, I cant seem to get the alignment of the nav menu right to vertically align right above the underline in the header.

```
        <header>
            <div>
                <img id="headerimage" src="" />             
            </div>
            <nav id="headernav">
                <ul id="list">
                    <li class="menuitem">
                        <a href="">Link1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menuitem">
                        <a href="">Link2</a>
                    </li>                           
                </ul>
            </nav>          
        </header>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
background-color: #cccccc;
margin: 0;
}

#header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

header  {
margin: 0;
background-color: #cccccc;
}


height: 5%;
   width: 100%;
}

.menuitem {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

#headerimage {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How do I keep the links to the right of the page along with moving them above the border? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an option that keeps the header height percentage-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS snippet has some typos, it probably should be:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin: 0;
}

header  {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.menuitem {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#headerimage {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

So you need to correct that.
Having a header that is 5% of the height of the page doesn't make a great deal of sense to me, and because the `menuitem` items are floated right, they don't have any block effect on the header content.

If you gave the header a fixed height that was big enough, e.g. `height: 80px;` then it would display as you want.

**EDIT:**

An alternative is to give the `menuitem`s a relative position, then offset the top by the height of the image in the header (it's the only element with a fixed height), and apply the border to the `div` enclosing the header image (see http://codepen.io/raad/pen/oyncv):

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img id="headerimage" src="" />             
  </div>
  <nav id="headernav">
    <ul id="list">
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="">Link2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="">Link1</a>
      </li>                           
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin: 0;
}

header  {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.imagecontainer {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.menuitem {
  position: relative;
  top: -36px;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

#headerimage {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Should you use pixels instead of percents then? When specifying dimensions?

Comment: @user3781214 percent-sized elements are fluid, i.e. they expand/contract with the page. Whilst that is useful in lots of places, sometimes it's not needed and a fixed size may be better. Does the header need to expand/contract in order to remain a set proportion of the page height?

Comment: No, not really. I was just thinking with different screen sizes and resolutions, percentages may be better.

Comment: @user3781214 - well, I have a couple of solutions for a fixed or percentage-based header height, so take your pick =)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#headernav {
 float: right;
}

#headernav ul li {
 display: inline;
}
```

This will `float` the `nav` to the right and `display` your list `inline` so each bullet is side-by-side.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsukasadt/puf0ws3x/

Comment: If you add a border to the header, the links are now below that border.

Comment: Move the `nav` inside the `div` of the `header`.  Updated JSFiddle with a border added to the `header` element: http://jsfiddle.net/tsukasadt/puf0ws3x/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfpzzao7/

```
<header>
    <div class="headerimage-container">
        <img id="headerimage" src="" />             
    </div>
    <nav id="headernav">
        <ul id="list">
            <li class="menuitem">
                <a href="">Link1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menuitem">
                <a href="">Link2</a>
            </li>                           
        </ul>
    </nav>          
</header>


html, body {
height: 100%;
background-color: #cccccc;
margin: 0;
}

#header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

header  {
margin: 0;
background-color: #cccccc;
}


height: 5%;
   width: 100%;
}

.menuitem {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

#headerimage {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.headerimage-container {
    display: inline-block;
}

#headernav {   
    display: inline-block;
}
#headernav li {   
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```